Using Cypress to test React app with Yjs Websocket server backend
Hi I am developing a collaborative tool using react and Yjs. The tool in question is a spreadsheet and I wanted to do some E2E testing to prove the correctness. I intented to use cypress to do this but for some reason I am having issues when opening the app, as for some reason it cannot connect to the websocket server, which is the provider for the Yjs data. The connection works perfect when opening any other browser, but when using cypress it gives me the Error message:
Firefox cannot establish a connection to the Server ws://localhost:1234/spreadsheetData

In the typescript file of my Spreadsheet component I establish the connection to the websocket server like this:
const yDoc = new Y.Doc();
const websocketProvider = new WebsocketProvider(
    'ws://localhost:1234',
    'spreadsheetData',
    yDoc
);


const yMap = yDoc.getMap<Map<Cell>>('spreadsheet');
const yColumns = yDoc.getArray<string>('columns');
const yRows = yDoc.getArray<string>('rows');

Then I use the Yjs as normal in the component itself. I am using the basic cypress configuration, as I have just started and do not know much about it. My cypres.config.ts file looks like this:
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
        },
    },
});

And the commands that I am using to start the app and cypress are these:
npx y-websocket-server
npm run dev
npm run cypress:open

"cypress:open": "cypress open"
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \" vite --host\" \"vite --host\""

Am I doing something wrong when starting cypress or is there something missing in the config file for it to be able to access websocket servers? Thanks in advance for the help!

How are the startup commands configured?

I Included the definitions of dev and cypress:open in my question. Dev starts two instances of react, on ports 5173 and 5174 and cypress:open is the normal cypress starting command given in their documentation. As for npx y-websocket-server it is the command given in the repository for the y-websocket-server: https://github.com/yjs/y-websocket

Ok - are the three startup commands in a script? Or are you just calling them from the command line?

I am just calling them from the command line. First the websocket server, then dev and then cypress.

Since there is a server starting up, you might want to use the start-server-and-test package to ensure the server is up before the test starts running.

Starts server, waits for URL, then runs test command; when the tests end, shuts down server
{
   "scripts": {
       "start-server": "npm start",
       "test": "mocha e2e-spec.js",
       "ci": "start-server-and-test start-server http://localhost:8080 test"
   }
}


The "ci" script calls the package with parameters for the server script, the URL to wait for and the testing script. A Cypress example is here
The only thing is, the URL is http:// not ws://, but this issue Websocket support #298 gives a possible syntax for websockets.

Websocket is tcp, and the wait-on library supports waiting for tcp. I was able to get this working using the syntax tcp:3000 to wait for a websocket on port 3000
start-server-and-test start-websocket tcp:3000 run-tests

So, for your commands, I would try:
{
  "scripts": {
    "start-server": "npx y-websocket-server",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \" vite --host\" \"vite --host\"",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "ci": "start-server-and-test start-server tcp:5174 'dev && cypress:open'"
  }
}

Unfortunately I couldn't get the React/Yjs demo to run, so I haven't been able to check that the syntax is correct. If you still have problems and can point to a working React/Yjs repo, I can check further.

I am sure that the server is started before the tests are executed, as I am able to access the application on any other browser and interact with it no problem. When i then execute cypress it says it cannot connect to it. It also tries several times doing so, so there would be time enough for it to connect to the server.

Indeed, that crossed my mind since you are running the startup commands manually. Do you have a repo for the project?

Okey in doing a minimal repo to reproduce the error as i cannot share the original code, i found something interesting. This error only happens if you start two instances of your app at the same time, as I was doing in my npm run dev. I am using the concurrently packet and it seems that it only has the problem when i use that command. If I only start one instance, say with the command "vite", cypress can connect to the websocket server without issue. The repo I just made to reproduce the error is: https://github.com/GabrielSanchezGansinger/YjsSpreadsheetDemo

Excellent, looks like you solved it.

Not really because I wanted to use cypress to test concurrent behavior, or at least start two instances and test their interaction. But it seems that that won't work.

Ok, explains why you start two apps! Normally Cypress only handles one app instance at a time.

There is this Run Two Cypress Test Runners At The Same Time - Running concurrently which opens two Cypress runners, or this Test a Socket.io Chat App using Cypress which uses the test code as one side of the chat. I'll see how that might fit with your repo.
